# mysql where condition in a group by statement?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, where-clause

I have the following query. 
I'd need to pick only the oldest rows (by DATE column) within my group by. keeping my conditions (where and group by).

```
SELECT 
table.*
from table
where views > $views AND sales>23
group by 
name
```

to be a bit clearer it is like passing frm this first table

```
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| name               | views     | DATE               |   sales   |
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| sue1               |       494 | 2014-06-23 12:08:29|   26      |
| sue2               |       494 | 2014-06-25 12:08:29|   34      |
| sue3               |       494 | 2014-06-27 12:08:29|   45      |
| sue4               |       520 | 2014-06-26 12:08:29|   56      |
| sue5               |       570 | 2014-06-24 12:08:29|   20      |
| sue5               |       570 | 2014-06-24 12:08:29|   28      |
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

to this second one

```
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|  name              | views     | DATE               |  sales    |
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| sue3               |       494 | 2014-06-27 12:08:29|    45     |
| sue4               |       520 | 2014-06-26 12:08:29|    56     |
| sue5               |       570 | 2014-06-24 12:08:29|    28     |
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

marko.c

I have tried doing a subselect as this

```
SELECT 
table.*
from table
where views > $views AND sales>23
and date in (select max(date) from table where views > $views AND sales>23)
group by 
name
```

but it's not working. anybody?

Comment: what is it telling you?

Comment: You can use ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1; This will give you result only 1 row with DATE IN descending order. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause and no aggregating functions. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the maximum overall date in your subquery but what you actually want is the minimum (oldest) date for each name.

```
SELECT 
    t1.*
from table t1
join (
    select 
        t2.name,
        min(t2.date) min_date
    from table t2
    where t2.views > $views AND t2.sales > 23
    group by t2.name
) t2 on t2.name = t1.name and t2.min_date = t1.date
where t1.views > $views AND t1.sales > 23
```

Answer (score 0):

as a first pass I honestly am not sure what you want. I think your request is to get all unique views by oldest date... but in any case if you want the oldest dates for each thing then just do your group after ordering it.

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT 
    table.*
    FROM table
    WHERE views > $views AND sales>23
    ORDER BY date
) AS t
GROUP BY name;
```

---

When you do an aggregate on a date think of it backwards..

```
MAX(date) will give you the NEWEST date because it is the greatest date. 
MIN(date) will give you the OLDEST date because it is the oldest / smallest date.
```

so if you wanted to do your other posted query you could do

```
SELECT 
table.*
from table
where views > $views AND sales>23
and date in (select MIN(date) from table where views > $views AND sales>23)
group by 
name
```

and see if the MIN(date) would do the trick